# Uploading a sketch without using the usb cable

Tags: arduino-uno

I've lost my usb cable used to upload a Sketch to my arduino from my laptop. I do have my Bluetooth 4.0 module. Can I use it to upload my sketches?

Comment: What bluetooth module is is exactly?

Comment: You can use the ICSP pins, but you can't drive those with Bluetooth. https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/arduinoISP

Comment: In your case, it would be easier to buy a new cable. But you asked a very interesting question in general. I'll have to think about it. Some thoughts: If you did not connect the USB to Serial part of the Arduino, you should be able to connect the RX and TX pins of the Arduino to the Bluetooth module (if the module is connectable to an UART see @chrisl s comment) ). Then you need a driver on the Laptop that simulates the Bluethooth connection to the Module as a COMx port (like to USB to SERIAL driver does). Possibly you need access to the reset pin also.

Comment: Specifically I asked about the module, because every bluetooth slave device will give the master specific endpoint types (could be audio, HID or Serial interface for example). Devices like HC-06 and HC-05 will present Serial interface endpoints. The OS of the PC should then handle the bluetooth device accordingly and create a virtual com/serial port for it, that you can use. But we currently cannot know, if your bluetooth module does this.

Comment: I think @chrisl explained it well.  In case you did not understand, inside Bluetooth, like inside USB, there exists many protocols that people do not think about as the computers "just take care of it".  You would need to use the Bluetooth serial port protocol on your computer and have on hand some sort of Bluetooth adapter hardware that supports the Bluetooth serial protocol complete with serial port wires that are logic level compatible with the particular Arduino processor you are using.  However, after thinking about all that, clearly, it would be much easier to purchase a new USB cable.